# Set up Ubuntu 14.04 VirtualBox guest so that it doesn't care how Windows host is connected to the internet

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

I'm using a bridged adapter, and sometimes switch between wireless and ethernet which means switching adapter type in the network settings. Also, VB won't connect when on my wireless at work (secured or guest). Sometimes I can get connected by using my phone as an ethernet hotspot via USB connection.

Ugh.

Is there a way to configure VB so that it is agnostic as to how Windows is connected to the internet?

Ubuntu 14.04 as VirtualBox guest under Windows 10.

Under NAT, Ubuntu connects, but no internet access.

**ifconfig:**

```
abalter@U1:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:68:82:d2  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe68:82d2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:515 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2896 (2.8 KB)  TX bytes:77547 (77.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:72 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5012 (5.0 KB)  TX bytes:5012 (5.0 KB)

abalter@U1:~$
```

**route -n:**

```
abalter@U1:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
abalter@U1:~$
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
abalter@U1:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
#auto eth1
#iface eth1 inet dhcp
abalter@U1:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but I have had the same problem you are facing and so I'm pondering a solution - have you tried bridging the two adapters in Windows? You may then be able to attach your vbox bridge to the windows bridge (or either adapter) and get a usable connection. Just a thought, which I know there are some potential issues with - so let me know if it works!

Comment: Which two adapters do you mean? How would I bridge them? Not familiar with doing that.